# Redis - How to delete fields from the redis hashmap stored at the key using prefix pattern?

Tags: redis

I have want to delete field in redis hash by pattern (more specifically prefix). I tried following and it doesn't work.

```
hdel <some_key> <prefix>*
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Redis does not provide a way to bulk remove keys that match a specific pattern. However, we can leverage the power of the command line to perform this action.

We will use the xargs to build and run commands back to Redis for this one. An example is as shown below:

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern "prefix*" | xargs redis-cli del
```

Comment: I believe OP is asking about filtering field names from a hash type key, not key names

Comment: Thanks for answering, however as @usuario said the question is about deleting fields from the hash stored at key and not deleting the key.